# Join the same table in a while loop with TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

How can I join the same table an arbitrary number of times to itself with a while loop in TSQL?

I have the table `TABLEDATA` which has 3 columns: `name`, `id` and `parentId` so my idea is having a table `Tn` defined by:

```
SELECT * FROM
TABLEDATA A1
LEFT JOIN TABLEDATA A2 ON A1.parentId= A2.id
LEFT JOIN TABLEDATA A3 ON A2.parentId= A3.id
.
.
.
LEFT JOIN TABLEDATA An ON A(n-1).parentId= An.id
```

With T1 being:

```
SELECT * FROM
TABLEDATA A1
```

And a variable:

```
DECLARE @nullsInN int =
(SELECT count(*) as nullsInN 
    FROM Tn
    WHERE An.idParent IS NOT NULL)
```

With the while statement `@nullsInN > 0` and break whenever it reaches 0.

Any alternative solution is welcomed.

Comment: This has been asked many times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-query+sql-server

Comment: @Martin Mas check my answer

Answer (score 2):

you will need to create a dynamic query.
build a text of query in the loop and then after loop execute it:

```
DECLARE @sql Varchar(max) 

declare @i INT = 1
declare @j INT = 2
declare @nullsInN INT = 1

set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLEDATA A1 ' + char(13)

WHILE @nullsInN <= (SELECT count(*) FROM Tn  WHERE An.idParent IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   SET @sql += 'LEFT JOIN TABLEDATA AS A' + CAST(@j AS VARCHAR(5)) + 
     ' ON A' + CAST(@j AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.parentId= A' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.id ' + char(13)


   SET @i= @i+ 1
  SET @j= @j+ 1
  SET @nullsInN = @nullsInN + 1
END

print(@sql)
EXECUTE @sql
```